# how to concatenate multiples nodes using xpath

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0

I'm looking a way to get the following string using Xpath 2.0 only:

AAA-Site-1.test.com,BBB-Site-1.test.com

```
<SystemRoot SystemName='Xpath Test'>
     <SystemRoot SystemDomain='test.com' SystemName='AAA-Site-1'>
      <Product InstallDate='11/01/2012' ProductName='AAA'/>
    </SystemRoot>
    <SystemRoot SystemDomain='test.com' SystemName='BBB-Site-1'>
      <Product InstallDate='11/01/2012' ProductName='BBB'/>
    </SystemRoot>
</SystemRoot>
```

I tried concat and then string-join, but I get "too many values" ...

```
concat(/SystemRoot/SystemRoot/@SystemDomain,'.',/SystemRoot/SystemRoot/@SystemName)
```

Is it possible to achieve by using XPath 2.0 only ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
string-join(/SystemRoot/SystemRoot/concat(@SystemName, ".", @SystemDomain),
            ",")
```